# Confusion around NSMutableArray and NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have the following code:

```
NSLog(@"items: %d", [items count]);
NSLog(@"allObjects: %d", [self.allObjects count]);

[self.allObjects addObjectsFromArray:items];

NSLog(@"allObjects: %d", [self.allObjects count]);
```

Which produces the following output:

```
items: 7
allObjects: 0
allObjects: 0
```

items is a NSArray

allObjects is a NSMutableArray.

I'm confused as to why the objects in items are not being added to allObjects. I expect it's something simple, but there is a hole in my understanding here.

Comment: can you post the code where you instantiate allObjects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me guess. `self.allObjects` is `nil`. Sending messages to `nil` is a no-op.

Comment: *facepalm* Might have to call it a day. Ugh.